# parsing the id value by giving a known td?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

With the help of firePath, I got this:

```
.//*[@id='#table-row-51535240d7037e70b9000062']/td[1]
```

Parot of My HTML looks like this:

```
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
      <tr>
       <tr id="#table-row-51535240d7037e70b9000062"> #this is the id that i want to get
      <td>             54           </td>            #this is the td that i know
      <td>
      <td>
       <td>Open</td>
    <td/>
```

What i really want to do here is, by giving the td value (54), I want to be able to get the id (parse the id), any hints how can i achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

PS: sorry for my English, and for my lack of knowledge :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your HTML is invalid (because it contains nested `<tr>` nodes). Nokogiri may be able to parse it, but if you can you should fix it before that.

You can fetch that id by the following ruby code:

```
doc.at_xpath("//td[contains(text(), '54')]/..")['id']
```

1. `//td[contains(text(), '54')]` will grab all the `<td>` nodes which contain `54`, `/..` will go to their parents.
2. [`Document#at_xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_xpath) will fetch only the first matching item
3. `['id']` will get the attribute of the matching node.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast reply, i will give it a try now !

Comment: if you have a minute, could you please explain to met what's going on in this code ? :)

Comment: why the html is bad? i only copied a part of it, not the full thing.

Comment: May i ask how did you try the code? i tried to run it inside a Capybara test suit,because i want to delete the element with that specific id, but failed, any hints ?

Comment: I created an HTML document from your example, and opened that with `Nokogiri::HTML(File.open('example.html'))`

Comment: the problem i am facing now is, that the html is inside a page that requires the user to be loged-in, and i am trying to run the code that finds the ID from inside a Capybara test (that logs in the user), so i couldn't just send the url of the page to the .open() :( . i created a .rb file, and wrote a method inside it, to receive the url and give me back the id, and then i called that method from inside the capybara test, but it always fails with :Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory message

Comment: Let's ask that in a different question.

Answer (score -1):

Using jquery

```
$(function(){
    // (i dont know if you have id for that td or not, it will be more easy if u do have id for that td)
    console.log($('table tbody tr td:first').closest('tr').attr('id')); // you can remove :first if you want to.
});
```

Oops, I misread your question, and one more thing, there is a problem in your tr tag.

Comment: `54` is the content, not the id

Comment: But you're not solving the problem then. It does not fetch the `<td>` with the `54` as content.

Comment: Ive edited and posted a suitable answer for you. Can you please try it. And yes please read the comment carefully written within the code section.